# Shiny Interactive Components Not Loading in Flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I'm trying to create a flexdashboard with some Shiny interactive components, but my Shiny components are not loading as expected. When I directly "Run Document" the flexdashboard with Shiny components works perfectly fine. However, if I try to run it from console through the following code:

```
rmarkdown::run("testing.Rmd", shiny_args = list(port = 5050, host = "0.0.0.0"))
```

The goal of doing this through console was to have the potential to share the shiny dashboard via LAN network as described here:
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799722/hosting-and-setting-up-own-shiny-apps-without-shiny-server/26800937#26800937)

The Shiny graph does not appear, while my non-Shiny graphs do load.

Any insight/solution is greatly appreciated!

I've tried messing around with a very small data set, and I encounter the same problem. I believe there is something lacking in the rmarkdown::run code.

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out your YAML. When I had the same issue ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75390324/flexdashboard-with-shiny-wont-render-graphs)), the fix ended up being removing an indent before `runtime: shiny`