# Flexdashboard Tabs Not Displaying Content Properly in R 4.3

Tags: r, plotly, r-markdown, flexdashboard

#### Issue:

I am trying to compile a report using `flexdashboard` in R 4.3. When I try to select an item on a tab which contains multiple sub-tabs, the content shows up for a split second and then disappears. I had a coworker attempt to run this report, and he was able to successfully run the report without issues.

#### Reproducible Example:

````
```r Critical Individual
==========================

Row {.tabset .tabset-fade}
-------------------------------------
   
### `r names(tmpindv[[1]][[1]][1])`

```{r}
tmpindv[[1]][[1]][[1]]



### `r names(tmpindv[[1]][[1]][2])`

```{r}
tmpindv[[1]][[1]][[2]]
````

#### Packages In Question:

Me:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

time zone: America/Chicago
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] openxlsx_4.2.5.2    knitr_1.43          plotly_4.10.2       flexdashboard_0.6.2 colorspace_2.1-0    cowplot_1.1.1       ggrepel_0.9.3      
 [8] Rspc_1.2.2          qicharts_0.5.8      janitor_2.2.0       readxl_1.4.2        lubridate_1.9.2     forcats_1.0.0       stringr_1.5.0      
[15] dplyr_1.1.2         purrr_1.0.1         readr_2.1.4         tidyr_1.3.0         tibble_3.2.1        ggplot2_3.4.2       tidyverse_2.0.0    
[22] pacman_0.5.1       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] gtable_0.3.3        xfun_0.39           bslib_0.5.0         htmlwidgets_1.6.2   latticeExtra_0.6-30 lattice_0.21-8      tzdb_0.4.0         
 [8] crosstalk_1.2.0     vctrs_0.6.3         tools_4.3.1         generics_0.1.3      parallel_4.3.1      fansi_1.0.4         pkgconfig_2.0.3    
[15] data.table_1.14.8   RColorBrewer_1.1-3  lifecycle_1.0.3     compiler_4.3.1      deldir_1.0-9        munsell_0.5.0       snakecase_0.11.0   
[22] htmltools_0.5.5     sass_0.4.6          yaml_2.3.7          lazyeval_0.2.2      crayon_1.5.2        pillar_1.9.0        jquerylib_0.1.4    
[29] ellipsis_0.3.2      cachem_1.0.8        zip_2.3.0           tidyselect_1.2.0    digest_0.6.31       stringi_1.7.12      labeling_0.4.2     
[36] fastmap_1.1.1       cli_3.6.1           magrittr_2.0.3      utf8_1.2.3          withr_2.5.0         scales_1.2.1        bit64_4.0.5        
[43] timechange_0.2.0    rmarkdown_2.23      httr_1.4.6          jpeg_0.1-10         bit_4.0.5           interp_1.1-4        cellranger_1.1.0   
[50] png_0.1-8           hms_1.1.3           evaluate_0.21       viridisLite_0.4.2   rlang_1.1.1         Rcpp_1.0.10         glue_1.6.2         
[57] vroom_1.6.3         rstudioapi_0.14     jsonlite_1.8.7      R6_2.5.1
```

Coworker:

```
> sessionInfo()R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=C                             LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] knitr_1.42          plotly_4.10.1       flexdashboard_0.6.1 colorspace_2.1-0    cowplot_1.1.1       qicharts_0.5.8     
 [7] kableExtra_1.3.4    bizdays_1.0.13      ggthemes_4.2.4      readxl_1.4.2        ggenealogy_1.0.1    tidylog_1.0.2      
[13] lattice_0.20-45     writexl_1.4.2       pander_0.6.5        gridExtra_2.3       janitor_2.2.0       ggrepel_0.9.3      
[19] Rspc_1.2.2          qcc_2.7             lubridate_1.9.2     forcats_1.0.0       stringr_1.5.0       dplyr_1.1.1        
[25] purrr_1.0.1         readr_2.1.4         tidyr_1.3.0         tibble_3.2.1        ggplot2_3.4.1       tidyverse_2.0.0    
[31] RODBC_1.3-20        pacman_0.5.1       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.4.6          sass_0.4.7          jsonlite_1.8.4      viridisLite_0.4.1   bslib_0.5.0         latticeExtra_0.6-30
 [7] cellranger_1.1.0    yaml_2.3.7          pillar_1.9.0        glue_1.6.2          digest_0.6.31       RColorBrewer_1.1-3 
[13] rvest_1.0.3         snakecase_0.11.0    htmltools_0.5.5     clisymbols_1.2.0    pkgconfig_2.0.3     bookdown_0.33      
[19] scales_1.2.1        webshot_0.5.5       svglite_2.1.1       jpeg_0.1-10         tzdb_0.3.0          timechange_0.2.0   
[25] generics_0.1.3      cachem_1.0.8        withr_2.5.0         lazyeval_0.2.2      cli_3.6.1           deldir_1.0-6       
[31] magrittr_2.0.3      evaluate_0.21       fansi_1.0.4         MASS_7.3-57         xml2_1.3.3          data.table_1.14.8  
[37] rsconnect_1.0.1     tools_4.2.1         hms_1.1.3           lifecycle_1.0.3     interp_1.1-4        munsell_0.5.0      
[43] compiler_4.2.1      jquerylib_0.1.4     systemfonts_1.0.4   rlang_1.1.0         rstudioapi_0.15.0   htmlwidgets_1.6.2  
[49] rmarkdown_2.23      gtable_0.3.3        R6_2.5.1            zoo_1.8-12          fastmap_1.1.1       utf8_1.2.3         
[55] stringi_1.7.12      Rcpp_1.0.10         png_0.1-8           vctrs_0.6.1         tidyselect_1.2.0    xfun_0.38
```

#### Expected Behavior:

When I select an item on a tab, I expect the content to display and remain displayed. We expect to see control charts.

#### Actual Behavior:

The content shows up for a split second and then goes away.

#### What I've tried:

- A coworker attempted to run the report using R 4.2 and was able to successfully compile the report with no changes to the code. I am able to interact with the report normally when he complies it.
- Checked for console errors (none found)
- Checked for warnings in R (none found)

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75390324/flexdashboard-with-shiny-wont-render-graphs