# Scrollable table in R Markdown Flexdashboard?

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt, flexdashboard

I am creating a dashboard in R Markdown with flexdashboard. I would like to include a scrollable, downloadable table of data, and I know that the package DT has this functionality, but I keep getting an error that says Error: Argument of length 0.

Specifically, I'm using the following code in a flexdashboard:

```
iris %>%
  datatable()
```

This doesn't work with a flexdashboard output, but it does work in HTML markdown output. Is this a bug? Does the code need to be changed for flexdashboard? Or is there another way to accomplish this with flexdashboard?

Comment: Can you provide a reprex? That should work fine within flexdashboard

Comment: Without a more complete reprex it's hard to know what's going on here, but check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75390324/flexdashboard-with-shiny-wont-render-graphs to see if that helps